# How do I convert a Python 3 byte-string variable into a regular string?

Tags: python-3.x, string, type-conversion

I have read in an XML email attachment with

```
bytes_string=part.get_payload(decode=False)
```

The payload comes in as a byte string, as my variable name suggests.

I am trying to use the recommended Python 3 approach to turn this string into a usable string that I can manipulate.

The example shows:

> ```
> str(b'abc','utf-8')
> ```

How can I apply the `b` (bytes) keyword argument to my variable `bytes_string` and use the recommended approach?

The way I tried doesn't work:

```
str(bbytes_string, 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You had it nearly right in the last line. You want

```
str(bytes_string, 'utf-8')
```

because the type of `bytes_string` is `bytes`, the same as the type of `b'abc'`.

Comment: `str(bytes_string, 'utf-8', 'ignore')` Errors can be ignored by passing the third parameter.

Comment: That looks like it should be a comment to [pylang's answer](/a/49457333) (which addresses handling invalid input).  If (you believe that) there's nothing wrong with `bytes_string`, why would you want to ignore errors?

Comment: I am getting following error with your approach: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0: invalid start byte` for the following bytes string `b'\xbf\x8cd\xba\x7f\xe0\xf0\xb8t\xfe.TaFJ\xad\x100\x07p\xa0\x1f90\xb7P\x8eP\x90\x06)0'` @TobySpeight

Comment: Well @alper, that's not a valid UTF-8 string, so what did you expect?

Answer (score 58):

Call `decode()` on a `bytes` instance to get the text which it encodes.

```
str = bytes.decode()
```

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 230: invalid start byte

Comment: @JuhaUntinen your encoding is probably not utf-8.

Comment: How to filter (skip) non-UTF8 charachers from array?

Comment: Use `str = bytes.decode("utf-8)` to use a diffirent encoding. Replace utf-8 to the encoding you want.

Answer (score 13):

> How to filter (skip) non-UTF8 charachers from array?

To address this comment in @uname01's post and the OP, ignore the errors:

**Code**

```
>>> b'\x80abc'.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
'abc'
```

---

**Details**

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type), here are more examples using the same `errors` parameter:

```
>>> b'\x80abc'.decode("utf-8", "replace")
'\ufffdabc'
>>> b'\x80abc'.decode("utf-8", "backslashreplace")
'\\x80abc'
>>> b'\x80abc'.decode("utf-8", "strict")  
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0:
  invalid start byte
```

> The errors argument specifies the response when the input string can’t be converted according to the encoding’s rules. Legal values for this argument are `'strict'` (raise a `UnicodeDecodeError` exception), `'replace'` (use `U+FFFD`, `REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`), or `'ignore'` (just leave the character out of the Unicode result).

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATED:**

> TO NOT HAVE ANY `b` and quotes at first and end
>
> How to convert `bytes` as seen to strings, even in weird situations.

As your code may have **unrecognizable** characters to `'utf-8'` encoding,
it's better to use just str without any additional parameters:

```py
some_bad_bytes = b'\x02-\xdfI#)'
text = str( some_bad_bytes )[2:-1]

print(text)
```

```
Output: \x02-\xdfI
```

if you add `'utf-8'` parameter, to these specific bytes, you should receive error.

As PYTHON 3 standard says, `text` would be in utf-8 now with no concern.

Comment: result is "b'\\x02-\\xdfI#)'" which probably isn't what he wants

Comment: @GlenThompson it is just an example for unwanted conditions, that may happen. I use this specific text intentionally. If you mean text has a `b` in first of it, then I updated answer

Comment: so very thanks i'm searching for a way for remove the b'' of an string that have ansi character without encoding and lossing the characters, i'm new in python and don't know than i can reduce an array from start and beginning using indexes :O

Comment: @DiegoFernandoMurilloValenci , your welcome. Glad to I can help.